# Tips needed on concreting swing posts into to lawn

Tags: porch-swing

We bought our kids a swing and need a little advice on how best to proceed (as we're not big diyers.

Our gardens sloping so we need to dig each posts hole at different depths to level it out. This means that we'll need to first poor concrete to stand the post on and then fill the rest of the hole with soil.

My question is.. how best should we protect the post from the soil that will surround it?

Comment: Are the posts metal or wood? You don't want to concrete in wood posts.

Comment: Definitely sit the posts on top of concrete, not embed the wood in concrete.    Why do you need to put dirt on top of the concrete in the hole, why not gravel, or cut the post shorter?

Answer (score 0):

> **we'll need to first poor concrete to stand the post on and then fill the rest of the hole with soil.**

The best solution is to dig the holes, fill the bottom with a foot of gravel for the post to stand on,  put the posts in place and then concrete around the post. Water running down the post can drain into the gravel.

If you stand a wooden post on concrete it will rot quickly.

I would use pressure-treated timber (or a species that is rot-resistant).
I would check it annually for rot and expect to replace it in 10 years.

Comment: I'm using the posts that came supplied that I think are weather treated but guess not treated for being under soil. I'm not anticipating it being around for more than 10 years. Is there any Hint we could treat it with like a tape or something? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I put our swing on a sloping lawn. The way I did it was to cut a few inches off the bottom of three of the legs so that it would stand level on the grass, and then pour concrete pads for those to bolt down to.